# Install C++ compiler on windows 7 (live/online) without running .exe file?

Tags: c++, windows-7, command-line, compiler

How can I install software online (using command prompt) on windows without running exe file (either through GUI or cmd)? For example to install a c++ compiler on windows 7!

Comment: "Please let me know how can I do this?" is considered unneeded on the Stack Exchange network. Please remove it and do not include it in future questions.

Comment: You can unzip a Mingw-W64 tarball and use it, but it requires an exe file to run the compiler (g++.exe).

Comment: @JL2210, I cant run .exe file on my desktop, Actually using a system at public library since its free and I have none. It requires admin previliges to execute an exe file.

Comment: I think you mean "I can't run installers on my desktop". In that case, go to the command prompt and install Cygwin without administrator privileges.

Comment: If you can run Google Chrome, you can run g++.exe from MinGW-w64.